# Unit of Work Casting issue in Repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, repository-pattern

**Updated:** I am trying to get user repository using following code with repository pattern. I am getting the run time casting exception

**"Unable to cast object of type 'Bidstruct.Repository.Repository`1[Bidstruct.Entities.User]' to type 'Bidstruct.Repository.IUserRepository'" at this line**

**userRepo = (IUserRepository)authUnitOfWork.Repository();**

```
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
           private readonly IUnitOfWork authUnitOfWork;
           private readonly IUserRepository userRepo;

            public UserController(
                [Dependency("BidstructAuthUnitOfWork")] IUnitOfWork authUoW,
            {
                 authUnitOfWork = authUoW;
                 userRepo = (IUserRepository)authUnitOfWork.Repository<User>();
            }
      }

     public interface IUnitOfWork
     {
          IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class;
     }

     public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
     {
        private readonly IDbContext _context;
        private Hashtable _repositories;


       public IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
       {
          if (_repositories == null)
            _repositories = new Hashtable();

         var type = typeof (T).Name;
         if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
         {
            var repositoryType = typeof (Repository<>);

            var repositoryInstance = 
                Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType
                        .MakeGenericType(typeof (T)), _context);

            _repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
         }

        return (IRepository<T>) _repositories[type];
       }
    }
    // User Repository Interface
    public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
    {
    }
    public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
    { 
    }
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show code of your UserRepository? Concretely what interfaces it implements.

Comment: IMHO it is not a correct way to implement the UnitOfWork pattern. You may refer http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/ for better design

Comment: @ Senthil thanks for suggestion. I will surely look into this as well

Comment: @ Euphoric Here is my user repository class                                   public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
 {
 }

Comment: We need to know how you instantiante the instances. In this case where you create the new UserRepository instance.

Comment: @ Euphoric i have added create instance method implementation in above code

Answer (score 2):

That is simple. The implementation of `authUnitOfWork.Repository<User>()` returns instance of class that doesn't implement `IUserRepository`, but still implements `IRepository<User>`. There is nothing that stops this method from returning `IWhateverIWantRepository` as long as it implements `IRepository<User>`.

You could either change your design so this is enforced or enforce that all repositories implement `I{SomeEntity}Repository` instead of `IRepository<SomeEntity>`. Either of those would be pretty complex.

Error in your code is on those lines:

```
var repositoryType = typeof (Repository<>);
var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof (T)), _context);
```

This creates instance of `Repository<User>` and not `UserRepository`. The runtime doesn't know you actually want some class that is related, but different to `Repository<T>`. To fix it you either need to pass it the `UserRepository` type or register it beforehand. You cannot expect the runtime to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

try below thing u should put user as IRepository I guess..

```
private readonly IRepository<User> userRepo;
private readonly IRepository<User> roleRepo;
```